# Cannot convert model to tensorflowjs from tf hub

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am using tensorflowjs_converter to convert a tflite model to tensorflowjs model.
The repository can be download with web browsers but failed when using tensorflowjs_converter.

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_hub 'https://tfhub.dev/sayakpaul/lite-model/arbitrary-image-stylization-inceptionv3/dr/predict/1' ./web_model
```

It outputs an Http 404 but my connection is fine. When I run the example code it works fine and I downloaded it.

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_hub 'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v1_100_224/classification/1' ./web_model
```

If you can tell me the reason or you can successfully convert tflite model from the following URLs, I will appreciate it a lot. Thank you so much.

https://tfhub.dev/sayakpaul/lite-model/arbitrary-image-stylization-inceptionv3/dr/predict/1

https://tfhub.dev/sayakpaul/lite-model/cartoongan/dr/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#step-1-converting-a-tensorflow-savedmodel-tensorflow-hub-module-keras-hdf5-or-tfkeras-savedmodel-to-a-web-friendly-format) it says that you can only convert a "TensorFlow SavedModel, TensorFlow Hub module, Keras HDF5 or tf.keras SavedModel" to a TF.js model using the converter but no TFLite model.

So you either need to provide such a model to the converter or you can use the new [tfjs-tflite](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_tflite/0.0.1-alpha.4/) API to run inference on a TFLite model in the browser. From [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5q8BzYN4rqA), you can modify [Demo 2](https://goo.gle/3gLY79b) by loading `https://storage.googleapis.com/tfhub-lite-models/sayakpaul/lite-model/cartoongan/dr/1.tflite` instead and replacing all occurrences of `224` with `512` since the CartoonGAN model consumes and produces images of sizes 512x512. The demo then loads the TFLite model in the browser and runs inference on the input image. The same approach works with the arbitrary-image-stylization-inceptionv3 model (minus that it outputs no image but an embedding vector).

Unfortunately, there is no possibility to export the loaded TFLite model as a TF.js model, yet.